# PDO remote host file access not supported

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, dsn

So i'm extending PDO class to use for database connection whit mysql and want load external DSN `file(uri:file://../msql.dns)` but i received this error:

> Warning: PDO::__construct(): remote host file access not supported

And then,supposed, because there is nothing to load:

> *Warning: PDO::__construct(file://../msql.dns): failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in
>   /home/me/apps/app/testApp/class/Database2.php on line 12

and catched exception is telling: *invalid data source URI*

dsnfile contains: `'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=somebase', 'myuser', 'mypass'`

even if I leave only with this part `'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=somebase'` either with `PDO::__construct` or making an instance from object directly.

Answer (score 0):

Check your php.ini configuration if you have the option allow url fopen enabled, as described at this link:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen

Comment: allow_url_fopen = On and is not commented

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use absolute path instead of relative.

PDO use php-streams for loadin a this file and I found that the problem was that i'm expecting that php-streams look at the include_path and just do that when you are using fopen(), file_get_contents(), etc.

To others you must specify the complete path.

```
$conn = new PDO('uri:file://' . $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '../msql.dns');
```